# Is this long drywall crack a big concern?

Tags: drywall, crack

The house was built only 5 years ago. There were several hairline cracks after 1 year as the house started settling and the builder patched them, but more cracks have appeared since then.

My biggest concern is about a long crack on a pillar in the morning room (see attached photo) [image] [image]

I am very new to owning a home and have little DIY knowledge. I was going to start looking up youtube videos on fixing hairline cracks, but this one makes me think that I might need to hire a professional drywall repairer.

Here is another one that does not look as terrible, but still worse than the normal hairline cracks. This one is on the wall adjoining the stairs. The crack extends upward quite a bit in a straight line but is very thin towards the top. [image] [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s not a settlement crack. Settlement cracks are diagonal or run at an angle.

It’s metal corner trim popping loose. It’s caused by the lumber drying out and shrinking. You need to re-screw the metal corner trim down and re-apply mud (joint compound).

Comment: then repaint the post.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely, since the house is still relatively new, it's still finding equilibrium (settling). The splits also appear to be along the corner bead (metal strip that protects the drywall corner). Add additional screws or nails to prevent it from flexing before repair is made to cracks.

It's difficult to predict when a house will finally stop moving so it's best to be prepared for new cracks to develop in the future. If the reoccur continually have an inspector verify the foundation and floor joists have been installed correctly.